# Cherenkov radiation momentum approximation question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, speed-of-light, cherenkov-radiation

I am stuck a bit on a question to do with Cherenkov radiation.

The requirement stated for Cherenkov radiation to occur is that the charged particle travels at a velocity greater than light in the medium.

We are asked to derive the the condition that radiation only occurs when

$$ p > \frac{mc}{\sqrt{2\delta n}} $$,

where we are told that the refractive index of the medium is $n = 1 + \delta n$, where $\delta n \ll 1 $ and that $ 1- \beta \ll 1 $, where $\beta = \frac{v}{c}$.

I have worked out that as the speed of the particle, $v > c_{medium}$, then then $v > \frac{c}{n}$. But this just gives me that $p > \frac{mc}{n}$ which is not what is required. I am clearly missing something here (not sure if I need to consider relatavistic effects), but if someone could give me a hint to where I am going wrong that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Cherenkov radiation condition]

You must take into account the Lorentz factor in momentum equation at relativistic limits-here I've assumed 'm' to be the rest mass of particle.

Comment: Avoid sending screenshots: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10563/discouraging-the-use-of-textual-screenshots-in-questions

Comment: Thanks, was wondering if I needed to use the relativistic momentum but for some reason had confused myself thinking that it did not apply here because we are not boosting the frame.